# Ajax request sent fine but i didnt get the response

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I make an AJAX request like this

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST",url: "<?php echo site_url('home/view_most'); ?>",async: true,data: "view=most_booked", success: function(data)
{   
    if(data != 0)
    {
        $("#view_most").html(data);
    }
    else
     alert("Error");
    }
});
```

In controller i get through

```
public function view_most()
{
    $view_most = $this->input->post("view");
}
```

Comment: Your view_most() function doesn't echo any output.

Comment: So what response are you expecting then?

Comment: i have just echo the posted values...but no response from that.only blank page is shown

Comment: I didn't get any response in the firebug.only posted values are shown.

Answer (score 2):

The response that ajax request is what server echoes so you must echo some value to get the response and handle the response in your success function. In your case does not echo anything thats why you are not getting any response. For example:

```
public function view_most()
{
    $view_most = $this->input->post("view");
    echo '0';
}
```

Try this and you will get 0 as response.

Comment: No response from controller.response header is not shown in firebug and the Html page is blank.

Comment: did you enable the server compression??

Comment: where i have to enable the this?

Comment: you can find this in ./applicatio/config/config.php file $config['enable_server_compression'] if it is set to true set it to false.

Answer (score 0):

not too familiar with the php codeigniter platform but I think you are not returning any data and that is why you dont see any data.. I am guessing you need to do something like the following at the end of your action code.

```
$this->load->view(viewName);
```

Thus your action code should be

```
public function view_most()
 {
      $view_most = $this->input->post("view");
      $this->load->view($view_most);
 }
```

Here is a quick introduction of AJAX on codeigniter: http://mrforbes.com/blog/2009/01/a-quick-code-igniter-and-jquery-ajax-tutorial/

Comment: public function view_most()
  {
    $view_most = $this->input->post("view");

Comment: i returning data to the view file..but it didnt give any output,only blank page is shown.